# Linux getting same values on different text files

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have two text files with different outputs. I would like to find the common lines by comparing these two files. This is just an example but I'm finding common values. file2.txt contains 2 columns.

file1.txt contains:

```
12XVGAS4RJQ3wZopCc7bvjRSjHBrRR9bmw 
12XVGsHANa9s4Szkmk73nTC5vTJHdFfx7w 
12XVGwB6c72mmQCqEwCQtbuKmStw5RqW3X 
12XVHEx5yorWhjxzFHMBW1ynPVCNwWfiDR
19vLAtK2PivKYB1ZT1J7dykw3rYga4SoVu
```

file2.txt contains:

```
125jHr5Gu4frTE3vqqf7w826wAGbvwUbo2  300
125JHs2AGKNuiSe7LGhVXEe4p6pasXiVme 100
12XVGwB6c72mmQCqEwCQtbuKmStw5RqW3X 900
12XVHEx5yorWhjxzFHMBW1ynPVCNwWfiDR 1000
19vLAtK2PivKYB1ZT1J7dykw3rYga4SoVu 0.93
```

This command will not work

```bash
comm -12 <(sort file1.txt) <(sort file2.txt)
```

I would like to extract the common values and have an output of

```
12XVGwB6c72mmQCqEwCQtbuKmStw5RqW3X 900
12XVHEx5yorWhjxzFHMBW1ynPVCNwWfiDR 1000 
19vLAtK2PivKYB1ZT1J7dykw3rYga4SoVu 0.93
```

How will I get this output?

Comment: You cannot use `comm` for the purpose because it compares whole lines.  The two files presented do not have any whole lines in common.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `join`:

```bash
join <(sort file1.txt) <(sort file2.txt)
```

Output:

```
12XVGwB6c72mmQCqEwCQtbuKmStw5RqW3X 900
12XVHEx5yorWhjxzFHMBW1ynPVCNwWfiDR 1000
19vLAtK2PivKYB1ZT1J7dykw3rYga4SoVu 0.93
```

Comment: dinging for performing `sort` on ***input*** instead of on ***output***

Comment: It's not every day that I learn of a command that was totally unknown to me.  `join` -- who knew?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that, like in the example you provided, neither file has duplicate first field values then using any awk:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]; next} $1 in a' file1.txt file2.txt
12XVGwB6c72mmQCqEwCQtbuKmStw5RqW3X 900
12XVHEx5yorWhjxzFHMBW1ynPVCNwWfiDR 1000
19vLAtK2PivKYB1ZT1J7dykw3rYga4SoVu 0.93
```